# Как рекурсивно вывести список файлов в папке?

Tags: javascript

Как вывести список файлов в папке рекурсивно, тоесть если в папке есть еще одно папка то вывести файлы для нее и тд.
Например

```
Папка
>Файл
>Файл
```

Должно вывести

```
Папка
Файл
Файл
```

Если так:

```
Папка
 Папка
   Файл
   Файл
Файл
Файл
```

Должно вывести:

```
Папка
  Папка
  Файл
  Файл
Файл
ФАйл
```

Answer (score 1):

С использованием **Node.js**:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function walk(dir_path, indent='') {
    const INDENT_CHAR = '    ';
    if (fs.existsSync(dir_path)) {
        console.log(`${indent}> [${path.basename(dir_path)}]`);
        fs.readdirSync(dir_path).forEach((item) => {
            const item_path = path.join(dir_path, item);
            if (fs.lstatSync(item_path).isDirectory()) {
                walk(item_path, indent + INDENT_CHAR);
            } else {
                console.log(`${indent}${INDENT_CHAR}> ${path.basename(item_path)}`)
            }
        });
    }
}

walk('/home/user/Documents/');
```

[Руководство по Node.js, часть 9: работа с файловой системой](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/424969/)